# Should we expect randomly chosen random variables to be independent?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, soft-question

**Setup:**

A probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ is a set $\Omega$ together with a sigma-algebra $\mathcal A$ defined on that set and a probability measure $P$ defined on that sigma-algebra. Consider the following interpretation:

A probability space consists of a set $\Omega$ of possible states of the world and collection $\mathcal A$ of subsets of $\Omega$ (events) about whose occurrence we have formed a consistent system of beliefs $P$.

In this interpretation, a random variable $X: (\Omega, \mathcal A) \to (\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$ can be understood as an experiment: If the true (unobservable) state of the world is $\omega$, the result of the experiment will be $X(\omega)$. Before the experiment occurs, our belief that the result of the experiment will lie in $B \in \mathcal B$ is $P(X \in B)=P(\{\omega: X(\omega) \in B\})$.

**Question:**

In the real world, if we conduct any two randomly chosen experiments somewhere in the universe then a-priori we would expect the associated random variables to be independent.

On the other hand, if we take two  "randomly chosen" random variables $X, Y$ defined on the same probability space then independence appears to be a "knife-edge property":
$$P(X \in B, Y \in B') = P(X \in B)P(Y \in B')$$
has to hold for *all* $B, B' \in \mathcal B$. So it appears that we should never expect two randomly chosen random variables to be independent.

How can the contradiction between these two intuitions be resolved? Also, what would be a "canonical" way of picking random variables at random?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the statement  $\forall B,B'\in\mathcal B[P(X\in B,Y\in B')=P(X\in B)P(Y\in B')]$ is very very unlikely to be true for two picked random variables $X$,$Y$? I don't see why. I could pick two distinct dice and it is immediate that the equality holds for their outcomes.

Comment: The problem here, is that as long as both the random variables are defined on the same sample space $\Omega$, they cannot be "randomly chosen". The correct notion of "randomly choosing" random variables, should be to define them on two different sample spaces $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$, and then look at the product measure on the product space $\Omega \times \Omega'$.

Comment: @Probabilist Also you could go for a new probability space where the outcome set is the collection of random variables $\Omega\to\mathbb R$. Though I admit: very artificial. I would not call it "the" problem but rather one of the problems here.

Comment: @drhab Why is that "artificial"? I think that is in fact **the** problem here. Without a probability space for the random variables the question is meaningless.

Comment: @Sam Artificial in the sense that I never engaged such constructions. Maybe I should have used other terminology. I see it as a problem (that can be solved) but cannot recognize it as *the* problem that is posed in the question.